# Remove some same-index elements from two lists based on one of them

Tags: python-3.x

Let's suppose that I have these two lists:

```
a = [{'id': 3}, {'id': 7}, None, {'id': 1}, {'id': 6}, None]
b = ['5', '5', '3', '5', '3', '5']
```

I want to filter both at the same-index based though only on `a` and specifically on filtering out the `None` elements of `a`.

So finally I want to have this:

```
[{'id': 3}, {'id': 7}, {'id': 1}, {'id': 6}]
['5', '5', '5', '3']
```

I have written this code for this:

```
a_temp = []
b_temp = []

for index, el in enumerate(a):

    if el:
        a_temp.append(a[index])
        b_temp.append(b[index])

a = a_temp[:]
b = b_temp[:]
```

I am wondering though if there is any more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Using `zip` is one approach

Comment: @Rakesh, I had in mind that It will be probably something with `zip` but it was not so clear to me how exactly in this case - thanks though ;)

Answer (score 2):

This solution

1. uses `zip()` to group corresponding elements of `a` and `b` together
2. Makes a list of 2-tuples of corresponding elements, such that the corresponding element of `a` is not None
3. Use the `zip(*iterable)` idiom to flip the dimensions of the list, thus separating the single list of 2-tuples into two lists of singletons, which we assign to `new_a` and `new_b`

```py
a = [{'id': 3}, {'id': 7}, None, {'id': 1}, {'id': 6}, None]
b = ['5', '5', '3', '5', '3', '5']

new_a, new_b = zip(*((x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b) if x))
# new_a = ({'id': 3}, {'id': 7}, {'id': 1}, {'id': 6})
# new_b = ('5', '5', '5', '3')
```

Comment: I see - thanks :) . To be honest, in the end the less pythonic solution is quite more readable I think for somebody who would read my code for the first time so I may even chose mine in the end. But it is certainly worth it knowing how to implement a more pythonic way like yours (upvote).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a simple solution, please try:

```
a = [{'id': 3}, {'id': 7}, None, {'id': 1}, {'id': 6}, None]
b = ['5', '5', '3', '5', '3', '5']
n = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    if a[i] is None:
        n.append(i)

for i in sorted(n, reverse=True):
    a.pop(i)
    b.pop(i)

a
[{'id': 3}, {'id': 7}, {'id': 1}, {'id': 6}]
b
['5', '5', '5', '3']
```